# how is the setView method in uiviewcontroller implemented?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to override the setter setView in a UIViewController subclass, the reason being is that setView in UIViewController autoreleases the view and I want to handle the memory management myself.

I'm trying override setView with my setView below:

```
-(void)setView:(UIView *)view
{
if (_view != view)
   {
    [_view release];
    _view = [view retain];
   }
}
```

But the compiler seems to not find the _view ivar, so im curious to know what the setView setter in UIViewController looks like? Or any other ways i can handle the view property's memory myself?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: my viewcontroller has a custom view which has a render loop and tries to access variables which have been released already. so im trying to release this view before it does this.

Comment: Normal practice would be to nil those variables upon release, and then check for nil when accessing them, no? Then if they're nil, you could cancel the render loop.

Comment: @mackworth yeh i was thinking of this approach but was i thought it would be messy. i ended up just leaving them in memory and just checking for properties to render the variables. leaving them in memory is probably a bad idea but i think it will do for now. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look roughly like this:

```
-(void)setView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (_view != view)
    {
        [_view release]; // Release _view, not view
        _view = [view retain];
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an autorelease part? to my understanding the view gets added to the autorelease pool

Comment: Another way to do it would be to: `[_view autorelease]; _view = [view retain]` without the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could always retain the view prior to setting.  It won't autorelease until the ref count < 1.

Comment: im actually trying to release it before it gets autoreleased